# Implementing Mockito's Answer interface to test all branches of method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm new to Mockito. I'm trying to use Mockito's `Answer` interface in my test class in order to test all branches of the `getAllFoo()` method. I want `isFooComplete()` to return `false` the first 2 times it is called, then return `true` the third time so that `actualFoo` contains 2 `Foo` objects at the end of the test.

The problem is that inside the for loop where I'm calling `getAllFoo()` on `service`, `false` is returned the first time, then the test becomes stuck in an infinite loop (as you would expect looking at the `getAllFoo()` method implementation).

How can I modify this test so that `getAllFoo()` returns `false` twice, then returns `true` and terminates the loop?

Service class:

```
public class ServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    FooService fooService;

    public Collection<Foo> getAllFoo() {
        Collection<Foo> allFoo = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean complete = fooService.isFooComplete();
        boolean available = fooService.isFooAvailable();
        while (!complete && available) {
            Foo foo = fooService.getAvailableFoo();
            allFoo.add(foo);
        }
        return allFoo;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();

    @Mock
    FooService fooService;

    class MyAnswer implements Answer<Boolean> {
        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock inovation) 
            throws Throwable {
            return (counter++ > 2) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllFoo() {
        MyAnswer myAnswer = new MyAnswer();

        MockFoo mockFoo = new MockFoo();

        when(fooService.isFooComplete()).thenAnswer(myAnswer);
        //when(fooService.isFooComplete()).thenReturn(false, false, true);
        when(fooService.isFooAvailable()).thenReturn(true);
        when(fooService.getAvailableFoo()).thenReturn(mockFoo);

        Collection<Foo> actualFoo = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actualFoo = service.getAllFoo();
        }            
        assertTrue(actualFoo.contains(mockFoo));
        assertEquals(2, actualFoo.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're not incrementing your counter. So you're counter is always 0. So a `counter++` before returning and changing your condition to `counter >= 2` should do it.

But it looks like you're implementing part of your FooService logic in this Answer. I think a `when(fooService.isFooComplete()).thenReturn(true, true, false)` might be a better choice here.

Comment: Good catch on the counter. I've edited to increment it. 

I made a mistake copying in my code initially: `service.getAllFoo()` should have been inside the loop (which I've also edited) - that's what was creating the problem: the first call returns false, then becomes stuck in an infinite loop before the counter can increment to the case where it eventually returns true. 

I tried your suggestion using `thenReturn(false, false, true)` instead of Answer and the problem still persists. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop. `while (!complete && available)` will never finish, because complete and available aren't changing within the while-block.

Probably you want to do this:

```
Collection<Foo> allFoo = new ArrayList<>();
boolean complete = fooService.isFooComplete();
boolean available = fooService.isFooAvailable(); 
while (!complete && available) {
    Foo foo = fooService.getAvailableFoo();
    allFoo.add(foo);
    complete = fooService.isFooComplete();
    available = fooService.isFooAvailable();
}
```

Comment: It may seem that way, but in practice `!complete` will always eventually evaluate to false, breaking out of the loop. The challenge is getting `fooService.isFooComplete()` to mock that behavior in the unit test.

Comment: I don't think so. If you set complete to false within the first test and available to true, then the while-loop won't end ever! You say that **!complete will always eventually evaluate to false** - but this is NOT correct. If `isFooComplete` will return false and `ifFooAvailable` will return true, then the while loop will be entered and never left because both variables don't ever change their value within the loop so the loop continues forever.